# Porque php y SQL server guardan en blanco

Tags: sql

Buen día me pregunta es saber por qué SQL server y php en mi formulario que son dos inputs y un save me guardan espacios en blanco al darle recargar o me agrega uno extra al darle guardar por qué mis datos se guardan bien pero tengo ese error y en mis datos estos usando de manera not null las columnas

```
<?php
 $PROCESO=$_POST['PROCESO'];
 $USUARIO=$_POST['USUARIO'];
 $ORDEN=$_POST['ORDEN'];
 $insertar="insert into asg112 (USUARIO,PROCESO,ORDEN) values('".$USUARIO."','".$PROCESO."','".$ORDEN."')";
 $rs = odbc_exec($conn, $insertar);
 if($PROCESO){ echo ' <div class="alert alert-success"> <strong>¡Éxito!</strong> Este cuadro de alerta podría indicar una acción exitosa o positiva. </div> <BR><BR>'
; echo $PROCESO ;
 echo "<BR><BR><center><input type='button' class='boton5' value='Atras' onClick='history.go(-1);'>"; } else{ }; 
?>

<?

include("conexion.php");


$sql="select * from asg112";
$exec=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
/*al darle recargar guarda vacios*/
$rows = "<center><table border 10 class='new'> 
            <tr class='cabecera'>
            <td class='old'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Usuario </td>
            <td class='old'>&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;Proceso</td>
            <td class='old'>&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;O.S /CLAVES</td>
            </tr>";

while(odbc_fetch_row($exec))
{   
    $rows.= "<tr class='cuerpo'>".
                    "<td class='t9'>".odbc_result($exec,'USUARIO')."</td>".
                    "<td class='t9'>&nbsp;&nbsp;".odbc_result($exec,'PROCESO')."</td>".
                    "<td class='t9'>&nbsp;".odbc_result($exec,'ORDEN')."</td>".
                    "</tr>";
    }
            $rows.="</table>";
            echo $rows;





    ?>
```

Comment: Espero que presiones sobre el boton [edit] y expliques mucho mejor que es lo que pasa, porque asi como esta no se entiende nada de nada. Ejemplos? el codigo que genera problemas?

Comment: Respuesta simple: porque así lo programaste. Para una respuesta más detallada, necesitas dar los detalles de lo que has hecho.

Comment: <?php

$PROCESO=$_POST['PROCESO'];
$USUARIO=$_POST['USUARIO'];
$ORDEN=$_POST['ORDEN'];

$insertar="insert into asg112 (USUARIO,PROCESO,ORDEN) values('".$USUARIO."','".$PROCESO."','".$ORDEN."')";
$rs = odbc_exec($conn, $insertar);


if($PROCESO){

echo '  <div class="alert alert-success">
    <strong>¡Éxito!</strong> Este cuadro de alerta podría indicar una acción exitosa o positiva.
  </div> <BR><BR>';
echo $PROCESO  ;

echo "<BR><BR><center><input type='button' class='boton5' value='Atras' onClick='history.go(-1);'>";

}
else{


};
?>

Comment: y este esta en index

Comment: <?
include("conexion.php");
$sql="select * from asg112";
$exec=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
/*al darle recargar guarda vacios*/
$rows = "<center><table border 10 class='new'> 
   <tr class='cabecera'>
   <td class='old'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Usuario </td>

{ 
 $rows.= "<tr class='cuerpo'>".
     "<td class='t9'>".odbc_result($exec,'USUARIO')."</td>".
     "<td class='t9'>&nbsp;&nbsp;".odbc_result($exec,'PROCESO')."</td>".
     "<td class='t9'>&nbsp;".odbc_result($exec,'ORDEN')."</td>".
     "</tr>";
 }
   $rows.="</table>";
   echo $rows;

Comment: <td class='old'>&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;Proceso</td>
   <td class='old'>&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;O.S /CLAVES</td>
   </tr>";
while(odbc_fetch_row($exec))